# Windows 8 Metro app Dialog Box change font color

Tags: javascript, css, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can I change the color of the button inside the MessageDialogBox in windows 8 metro using Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You will need to build your own flyout control based dialog for a fully customizable dialog experience.